# "You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits"

Tags: support, editing

How do I know the reasons behind this so I can improve myself?

And how do I know how many days?

Comment: To be fair, I looked through the edits and they do seem to give some improvements, if not a lot. We should all remember that this is a community-driven platform and we should be grateful for contributions by members.

Answer (score 3):

Because of revisions that don't add any value to the posts like this:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/229607/revisions
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/307513/revisions
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/282406/revisions
- ....

please be more careful of what you edit. Make sure the edits are meaningful and they are not used just so you can get the 2 reputation points or to bump your post to the top of the homepage.

Comment: Thats ridiculous. These are all but one my own posts, you cant get reputation points by improving your own posts and I was not even aware that editing my question is bumping it, this was not my intention. I just improved my posts. Why are these edits approved if they are bad? How many days am I banned?

Comment: And how does it make sense to bump my post of my own Q&A?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/282406/revisions

Comment: how is this an improvement? https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/282406/revisions Total ban was for 7 days.

Comment: how is it not an improvement, you can see the important text much easier since it is bold now. Why does it even care you, this is my own answer and I can decide if it is an improvement or not myself.

Comment: that's not true. Anyway. if you think an injustice was made you can always contact the Community managers in here: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: It is obviously easier to see the important text after the edit, so explain how it is not true. You act like I am a criminal for just improving my own answer, even though I did not get any benefit (bump, 2 points) out from it.